# Can DbContext be composed instead of inherited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simple-injector

Let's say I am doing a code-first development for a school and I have a `SchoolDbContext`. Most documentation on Entity Framework suggest you **derive** from `DbContext`:

```
public class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Student> Students => Set<Student>();
}
```

But my argument is `SchoolDbContext` is never a specialisation of `DbContext`, it is instead just making use of `DbContext` so in my opinion, `SchoolDbContext` should be **composed** of `DbContext`:

```
public class SchoolDbContext
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public SchoolDbContext(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IDbSet<Student> Students => _dbContext.Set<Student>();
}
```

In my composition root of an ASP.NET MVC application, I tried this composition approach by setting up my dependencies like this (using Simple Injector as an example):

```
private static void RegisterDependencies(Container container)
{
     // Assume I have a connection string SchoolDbContext
     container.Register(() => new DbContext("SchoolDbContext"), Lifestyle.Scoped);
     container.Register<SchoolDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
}
```

Web.config:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolDbContext"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This fails when I try to load `Students` with:

> The entity type Student is not part of the model for the current context.

When I change it back to the inheritance approach (i.e. invoking the default constructor `new SchoolDbContext()`) everything works perfectly.

Is my composition approach not supported by Entity Framework?

Comment: If your intention is to hide DbContext from the rest of the application, you can do both inheritance and composition.

Comment: @Steven, true, but I am just trying to see if there are ways to prefer composition over inheritance since I don't need most of the low level database API from `DbContext`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can DbContext be composed instead of inherited?

Short answer: **NO**

To quote the remarks from official documentation (emphasis mine)

> `DbContext` is usually used with a derived type that contains
>   `DbSet<TEntity>` properties for the root entities of the model. *These
>   sets are automatically initialized when the instance of the derived
>   class is created*....

There is more but it is too much to put in this answer.

Source [DbContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Is my composition approach not supported by Entity Framework?

If you look at the source code for `DbContext` there are internal methods that search the class for `DbSet`s and initializes them.

Mainly this section of code

```
/// <summary>
///     Initializes the internal context, discovers and initializes sets, and initializes from a model if one is provided.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model = null)
{
    DbConfigurationManager.Instance.EnsureLoadedForContext(GetType());

    _internalContext = new LazyInternalContext(
            this, internalConnection, model
            , DbConfiguration.GetService<IDbModelCacheKeyFactory>()
            , DbConfiguration.GetService<AttributeProvider>());
    DiscoverAndInitializeSets();
}

/// <summary>
///     Discovers DbSets and initializes them.
/// </summary>
private void DiscoverAndInitializeSets()
{
    new DbSetDiscoveryService(this).InitializeSets();
}
```

Any model you try to get will throw the same error as the model was not part of the context when it was initialized which can only happen if it was a member of a derived class.

[DbContext source code on Github](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs)